# nmcli do not show wlan card in user scope

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, networkmanager, nmcli

I am using NetworkManager Applet 0.8.1, centos 6.4 x86_64. nmcli version 0.8.1-107.el6. This is seems the latest version for this system release edition.

I am using edup ep-n1572 wifi card with chip rtl8192cu. I download driver for linux from edup website and installed successfully.

**The problem:**

`nmcli con list` not show wlan card and I could not activate it.

```
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
System eth0               3f6582f5-969a-4b27-aa38-3e3de30369ea   802-3-ethernet    system   Fri 28 Oct 2016 09:07:47 PM CST   
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL
```

When using NetworkManager GUI mode in xwindow, it works fine. I can see wifi ssids and connect one of them successfully. I start my machine as console mode and then using `startx` to xwindow gui mode. While NetworkManager GUI works well in a login session, `nmcli con list` can see infomation of a ssid in `user scope`, which the wireless card connected, in another login session which I openned using `ctrl-alt-F2`.

```
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
System eth0               3f6582f5-969a-4b27-aa38-3e3de30369ea   802-3-ethernet    system   Fri 28 Oct 2016 09:07:47 PM CST   
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              SCOPE    TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Auto myssidhere   3c0e2234-5edc-4054-8e62-b9dbdc279295   802-11-wireless   user     Fri 28 Oct 2016 10:52:10 PM CST
```

But when I logout from xwindow, it still can not show wireless information.

**Infos what I got in console mode using nmcli without any xwindows startup**

**nmcli nm**

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

**nmcli dev can show wireless card**

```
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE       
eth0       802-3-ethernet    disconnected
wlan0      802-11-wireless   disconnected
```

**iwconfig**

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**iwconfig wlan0 mode auto** not solve my problem

**iwlist scan,  nmcli dev wifi list, nm-tool, iw dev wlan0 scan** all can return ssids successfully

So It seems should not be a big problem, right? What should I do? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: `nmcli con` is about connection profiles, not devices (aka interface or link). You can create, modify and delete connection profiles with nm-connection-editor. A connection profile can be stored in the user session or globally. If you log out, you no longer see connections from the user session

Comment: Thanks @thaller. Is that mean that I can just copy the profile created by NetworkManager Applet 0.8.1 for nmcli? Where to find it? I logon in console mode and Gnome (using `startx` in console mode) with same user. But when I logout from Gnome, `nmcli` could not see the profile created by NetworkManager Applet.

Comment: I've already found profiles for NetworkManager Applet, which is located in `/home/myuser/.gconf/system/networking/`. But they are profiles for GUI. How create profiles for nmcli? Does [key files](https://people.freedesktop.org/~lkundrak/nm-docs/nm-settings-keyfile.html) work for this?

Comment: I create key file manually followed [0.8.1 code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/system-settings/plugins/keyfile/tests/keyfiles/Test_Wireless_Connection?id=80c16a1973c23e62cc07696168e03c93d0810253), but it still could not show wlan0

Comment: Have you done sudo ifconfig wlan0 up?